# pdflatex.ini missing - but it's there (MikTeX)

Tags: pdftex, miktex

When I try to compile the .tex-file, I get an error, telling me that the **pdflatex.ini** is missing in \tex\config\pdflatex.ini.
I went looking into the directory - and the file is there. But TeXWorks tells me:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-1.40.11 (MiKTeX 2.9)
miktex-pdftex.exe: The memory dump file could not be found.
miktex-pdftex.exe: Data: pdflatex.fmt
```

I also looked for **miktex-pdftex.exe**, and I found it in the bin.
Problem is, somehow I didn't got a new logfile.

I would appreciate some help with this. Thanks!

Comment: `\tex\config\pdflatex.ini` is a curious location. There should exists two pdflatex.ini (with different contents). One in `miktex\config` and the other (needed for the format generation) in `\tex\latex\config`. Try to build the pdflatex format in miktex settings.

Comment: yes, I'm sorry I forgot the "\latex" The file is also in   `miktex\config`.

Comment: It is not "the" file. They are both very different (open them in a editor and look) and are used for different purposes. So don't confuse them. Did you try to build the pdflatex format?

Comment: yes I did. I already compiled it at home with TeXnicCenter. Yes, I noticed that they are different, and I didn't copy them etc. They where already there after I installed MiKTeX.

Comment: "yes I did. I already compiled it at home with TeXnicCenter." Well you can't compile the format with TeXnicCenter. So you probably don't have a clue what the format is. Go to miktex-settings to the format tab. Click on the pdflatex entry and then on "build".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reinstalled MiKTeX and it solved the problem. Thank you very much for helbping me!

Comment: Could you please accept this answer (using the tick mark below the voting buttons) so that it is removed from the list of "unanswered questions". Thank you.

Comment: I wasn't able to do so. The yellow box tells me that I have to wait 21 more hours until I can accept it. Otherwise I would have already done so. :-( I'm sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried renewing MiKTeX's File Name Database?

You can find it in `Start > Programs > MiKTeX > Settings` or run command `mo` in command shell.
Then click Refresh FNDB.

Comment: Thank you very much, that is a good idea, but sadly doesn't solves my problem.