# metauml: Realization link doesn't work

Tags: metapost, metauml

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[shellescape]{gmp}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{mpost}[use]
input metauml;

Interface.A("Interface")
       ();

A.info.iAttributeStack.top := 0;
A.info.iAttributeStack.bottom := 0;

Class.B("Class")
       ()
       ();       

A.w = B.e + (50, 0);

drawObjects(A, B);

clink(association)(B, A);
\end{mpost}
\caption{association}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\begin{mpost}[use]
input metauml;

Interface.A("Interface")
       ();

A.info.iAttributeStack.top := 0;
A.info.iAttributeStack.bottom := 0;

Class.B("Class")
       ()
       ();       

A.w = B.e + (50, 0);

drawObjects(A, B);

clink(associationUni)(B, A);
\end{mpost}
\caption{associationUni}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\begin{mpost}[use]
input metauml;

Interface.A("Interface")
       ();

A.info.iAttributeStack.top := 0;
A.info.iAttributeStack.bottom := 0;

Class.B("Class")
       ()
       ();       

A.w = B.e + (50, 0);

drawObjects(A, B);

clink(inheritance)(B, A);
\end{mpost}
\caption{inheritance}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\begin{mpost}[use]
input metauml;

Interface.A("Interface")
       ();

A.info.iAttributeStack.top := 0;
A.info.iAttributeStack.bottom := 0;

Class.B("Class")
       ()
       ();       

A.w = B.e + (50, 0);

drawObjects(A, B);

clink(realization)(B, A);
\end{mpost}
\caption{realization}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\begin{mpost}[use]
input metauml;

Interface.A("Interface")
       ();

A.info.iAttributeStack.top := 0;
A.info.iAttributeStack.bottom := 0;

Class.B("Class")
       ()
       ();       

A.w = B.e + (50, 0);

drawObjects(A, B);

clink(aggregation)(B, A);
\end{mpost}
\caption{aggregation}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\begin{mpost}[use]
input metauml;

Interface.A("Interface")
       ();

A.info.iAttributeStack.top := 0;
A.info.iAttributeStack.bottom := 0;

Class.B("Class")
       ()
       ();       

A.w = B.e + (50, 0);

drawObjects(A, B);

clink(aggregationUni)(B, A);
\end{mpost}
\caption{aggregationUni}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\begin{mpost}[use]
input metauml;

Interface.A("Interface")
       ();

A.info.iAttributeStack.top := 0;
A.info.iAttributeStack.bottom := 0;

Class.B("Class")
       ()
       ();       

A.w = B.e + (50, 0);

drawObjects(A, B);

clink(composition)(B, A);
\end{mpost}
\caption{composition}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\begin{mpost}[use]
input metauml;

Interface.A("Interface")
       ();

A.info.iAttributeStack.top := 0;
A.info.iAttributeStack.bottom := 0;

Class.B("Class")
       ()
       ();       

A.w = B.e + (50, 0);

drawObjects(A, B);

clink(compositionUni)(B, A);
\end{mpost}
\caption{compositionUni}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\begin{mpost}[use]
input metauml;

Interface.A("Interface")
       ();

A.info.iAttributeStack.top := 0;
A.info.iAttributeStack.bottom := 0;

Class.B("Class")
       ()
       ();       

A.w = B.e + (50, 0);

drawObjects(A, B);

clink(dependency)(B, A);
\end{mpost}
\caption{dependency}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

This example shows all possible links between classes/interfaces as described on page 9 of metauml [documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/graphics/metapost/contrib/macros/metauml/doc/metauml_manual_0.2.5.pdf)

All links display correctly except for one. It is "realization". That link does not appear.

It now looks like this:

[image: classes]

How can it be fixed?

I use MetaPost, version 1.504 (MiKTeX 2.9)

This is what I get when I compile egreg's solution:

[image]

[Here](http://pastebin.com/iDncaCf0) you can find a log from metapost trying to generate realization link.

**EDIT:**

I found out that I have version older than 0.2.4 because the file `C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\metapost\generic\metauml\metauml_class_relations.mp` didn't contain definition of `realization`. Realization support was added in 0.2.4.

I did only one thing. I downloaded the newest version and replaced every file in `C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\metapost\generic\metauml`. This caused a "little" trouble.
The logs (`tmp+mp000X.log`) say that:

```
! I can't open file `metauml_component'.
l.77 input metauml_component
                            ;
Please type another input file name
! Emergency stop.
l.77 input metauml_component
                            ;
*** (job aborted, file error in nonstop mode)
```

I checked and mentioned file does exist. What should I do next?

Comment: I get many syntax errors from Metapost.

Comment: If the file is new in this package version maybe you need to refresh the file name database before it can be found.

Comment: OK, how can I do that?

Comment: I'm not a MikTeX user myself, but look [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12389/12850).

Comment: http://lmgtfy.com/?q=metauml+refresh+file+name+database :P

Comment: OK. It works finally :). 100 rep anyone ;) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the correct way to input the Metapost snippets:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[shellescape]{gmp}
\begin{document}

\begin{mpost}[use,mpsettings={input metauml;}]
Interface.A("Interface")
       ();
A.info.iAttributeStack.top := 0;
A.info.iAttributeStack.bottom := 0;
Class.B("Class")
       ()
       ();       
A.w = B.e + (50, 0);
drawObjects(A, B);
clink(association)(B, A);
\end{mpost}

\begin{mpost}[use,mpsettings={input metauml;}]

Interface.A("Interface")
       ();

A.info.iAttributeStack.top := 0;
A.info.iAttributeStack.bottom := 0;

Class.B("Class")
       ()
       ();       

A.w = B.e + (50, 0);

drawObjects(A, B);

clink(associationUni)(B, A);
\end{mpost}

\begin{mpost}[use,mpsettings={input metauml;}]

Interface.A("Interface")
       ();

A.info.iAttributeStack.top := 0;
A.info.iAttributeStack.bottom := 0;

Class.B("Class")
       ()
       ();       

A.w = B.e + (50, 0);

drawObjects(A, B);

clink(inheritance)(B, A);
\end{mpost}

\begin{mpost}[use,mpsettings={input metauml;}]

Interface.A("Interface")
       ();

A.info.iAttributeStack.top := 0;
A.info.iAttributeStack.bottom := 0;

Class.B("Class")
       ()
       ();       

A.w = B.e + (50, 0);

drawObjects(A, B);

clink(realization)(B, A);
\end{mpost}

\begin{mpost}[use,mpsettings={input metauml;}]

Interface.A("Interface")
       ();

A.info.iAttributeStack.top := 0;
A.info.iAttributeStack.bottom := 0;

Class.B("Class")
       ()
       ();       

A.w = B.e + (50, 0);

drawObjects(A, B);

clink(aggregation)(B, A);
\end{mpost}

\begin{mpost}[use,mpsettings={input metauml;}]

Interface.A("Interface")
       ();

A.info.iAttributeStack.top := 0;
A.info.iAttributeStack.bottom := 0;

Class.B("Class")
       ()
       ();       

A.w = B.e + (50, 0);

drawObjects(A, B);

clink(aggregationUni)(B, A);
\end{mpost}

\begin{mpost}[use,mpsettings={input metauml;}]

Interface.A("Interface")
       ();

A.info.iAttributeStack.top := 0;
A.info.iAttributeStack.bottom := 0;

Class.B("Class")
       ()
       ();       

A.w = B.e + (50, 0);

drawObjects(A, B);

clink(composition)(B, A);
\end{mpost}

\begin{mpost}[use,mpsettings={input metauml;}]

Interface.A("Interface")
       ();

A.info.iAttributeStack.top := 0;
A.info.iAttributeStack.bottom := 0;

Class.B("Class")
       ()
       ();       

A.w = B.e + (50, 0);

drawObjects(A, B);

clink(compositionUni)(B, A);
\end{mpost}

\begin{mpost}[use,mpsettings={input metauml;}]

Interface.A("Interface")
       ();

A.info.iAttributeStack.top := 0;
A.info.iAttributeStack.bottom := 0;

Class.B("Class")
       ()
       ();       

A.w = B.e + (50, 0);

drawObjects(A, B);

clink(dependency)(B, A);
\end{mpost}

\end{document}
```

I've left out the inessential captions and `figure` environments. This is the result.

[image]

Check the version of your MetaUML package. With version 0.2.5 it works: see

```
<texroot>/doc/metapost/metauml/README
```

for checking the version number. Use your package manager (MiKTeX or `tlmgr` for TeX Live) for updating.

Comment: I changed this and I still can't get the realization arrow. WHat could be wrong? Every other arrow is just fine.

Comment: @Ichibann Did you remove the `+mp00xy.mp` files?

Comment: egreg yes and realization still doesn't work...

Comment: I updated my question to show the output.

Comment: Sorry, but my `tmp+mp0004.mp` compiles perfectly. My `metauml` version is 0.2.5

Comment: I checked that I had older version of `metauml`. I replaced it with the newest one and... new problem arised. Details in original question.